# How to readjust x_axis scale of ggplot so that it focuses on certain range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to adjust the X axis of my ggplot, so that it is widened in a specific range, and you can see a certain range more specifically.

[image]

My plot looks like this right now, but the boxed region (-1e+6 < x < 1e+6) where all the red points are distributed is important as well. Is there any way to widen this wanted region?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```r
ggplot(...) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1e+6, 1e+6))
```